# Fit image in div which have more height than image

Tags: html, css

I have image which have less height than div where i want fit it. width of div is fixed. height of div is not fixed its dynamic. 
How to achieve this. I tried css
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
But its not working.

Comment: I'm assuming you're wanting the image to fill the entire div, without distorting the image. If that is true, do you want the DIV's height to match whatever the image height is, or do you want the image to grow larger to match the div, therefore cutting off part of the image?

Comment: Please include html and css files that doesn't work and a scetchup of what you want :)

Comment: I have two div side by side, right div contains some text with no fixed height. left div contains image, i want image take height of right div.

Comment: You want to scale the image so that it has the same height as a different element altogether? Ehm, Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with just css by making the left div and image position absolute and having it fit the height of a container whose height will be determined by the content in the right div.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="source.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Content which will determine height of both divs
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .outer {
    position: relative;
  }

  .left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%
  }

  .left img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .right {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property `object-fit` ([Current browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit))

Just set `object-fit: cover;` on the img

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit):

> cover
>
> The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while
>   filling the element’s entire content box: its concrete object size is
>   resolved as a cover constraint against the element’s used width and
>   height.

### [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/Qyadxp)